# Mocking external dependencies in Spring Boot integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

**Main question:** Is there any way to replace a bean with a mock object in the whole context of Spring and inject the exact bean to the test to verify method calls?

I have a Spring Boot application, and I'm trying to write some integration tests in which I'm calling the Rest APIs using `MockMvc`.

Integration tests run against an actual database and AWS resources using `Testcontainer` and `Localstack`. But for testing APIs which are integrated with `Keycloak` as an external dependency, I decided to mock `KeycloakService` and verify that the correct parameters are passed to the proper function of this class.

All of my integration test classes are a subclass of an abstract class called `AbstractSpringIntegrationTest`:

```
@Transactional
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = PostgresITConfig.DockerPostgreDataSourceInitializer.class, classes = {AwsITConfig.class})
public class AbstractSpringIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    public MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS;
}
```

Consider there is a subclass like the following class:

```
class UserIntegrationTest extends AbstractSpringIntegrationTest {
    
    private static final String USERS_BASE_URL = "/users";

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @MockBean
    private KeycloakService keycloakService;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(booleans = {true, false})
    void changeUserStatus_shouldEnableOrDisableTheUser(boolean enabled) throws Exception {
        // Some test setup here

        ChangeUserStatusRequest request = new ChangeUserStatusRequest()
                .setEnabled(enabled);

        String responseString = mockMvc.perform(patch(USERS_BASE_URL + "/{id}/status", id)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse()
                .getContentAsString();

        // Some assertions here

        Awaitility.await()
                .atMost(10, SECONDS)
                .untilAsserted(() -> verify(keycloakService, times(1)).changeUserStatus(email, enabled); // Fails to verify method call
    }
}
```

And this is the class that calls functions of the `KeycloakService` based on events:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class UserEventSQSListener {

    private final KeycloakService keycloakService;

    public UserEventSQSListener(KeycloakService keycloakService) {
        this.keycloakService = keycloakService;
    }

    @SqsListener(value = "${cloud.aws.sqs.user-status-changed-queue}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void handleUserStatusChangedEvent(UserStatusChangedEvent event) {
        keycloakService.changeUserStatus(event.getEmail(), event.isEnabled());
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
keycloakService bean.changeUserStatus(
    "rodolfo.kautzer@example.com",
    true
);

Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

After debugging the code, I understood that the bean mocked in `UserIntegrationTest` is not the same bean injected into the `UserEventSQSListener` class due to the context reloading. So, I tried other solutions like creating a mock object using `Mockito.mock()` and return it as a bean, and using [@MockInBean](https://github.com/antoinemeyer/mock-in-bean), but they didn't work as well.

```
    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestBeanConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public KeycloakService keycloakService() {
            KeycloakService keycloakService = Mockito.mock(KeycloakService.class);
            return keycloakService;
        }
    }
```

**Update 1:**

Based on @Maziz's answer and for debug purposes I change the code like the following:

```
@Component
public class UserEventSQSListener {

    private final KeycloakService keycloakService;

    public UserEventSQSListener(KeycloakService keycloakService) {
        this.keycloakService = keycloakService;
    }

    public KeycloakService getKeycloakService() {
        return keycloakService;
    }
...
```

```
class UserIT extends AbstractSpringIntegrationTest {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private UserEventSQSListener userEventSQSListener;

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, UserEventSQSListener> beans;

    private KeycloakService keycloakService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        ...
        keycloakService = mock(KeycloakService.class);
    }

@ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(booleans = {true, false})
    void changeUserStatus_shouldEnableOrDisableTheUser(boolean enabled) throws Exception {
        // Some test setup here

        ChangeUserStatusRequest request = new ChangeUserStatusRequest()
                .setEnabled(enabled);

        String responseString = mockMvc.perform(patch(USERS_BASE_URL + "/{id}/status", id)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse()
                .getContentAsString();

        // Some assertions here

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userEventSQSListener, "keycloakService", keycloakService);

        assertThat(userEventSQSListener.getKeycloakService()).isEqualTo(keycloakService);

        await().atMost(10, SECONDS)
                .untilAsserted(() -> verify(keycloakService).changeUserStatus(anyString(), anyBoolean())); // Fails to verify method call
    }
```

As you see the mock is appropriately replaced inside the `UserEventSQSListener` class:

[image: debug the injection]

Still, I got the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
keycloakService.changeUserStatus(
    <any string>,
    <any boolean>
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: You're sure that the LocalStack SQS setup for your integration test is working and the event arrives at your listener?

Comment: Yes. I do. At first, I thought the same, but If I inject the real `KeycloakService`s bean, the changes will be applied in the Keycloak side.

Comment: If the keycloakService mocked bean is not being injected, is the actual bean being initialised and calling the actual service?

Comment: I did not read the entire question, but `@TestConfiguration` with the override option will not work for you?

Comment: Since I've tested different solutions, I missed the track. Still, in some cases, the actual bean is initialized and injected to `UserEventSQSListener`, so the changes are applied to the Keycloak. In some cases, the `UserEventSQSListener` will be initialized again, and a new mocked object will be injected into it using the constructor, but the reference in the test class will not change. So another mock object will be called and the verification will happen on another mocked object and the error will be thrown. @ParthManaktala

Comment: "Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.": The only(^^) explanations are: Mock object is not "properly wired" (which we can exclude at this point(!?)); or: Something "in between `UserEventSQSListener/@SqsListener` and mock object" is not properly wired/ **mocked (away, silently)/not invoked in the test environment/runtime..** ; I think "parameters"/overloading is here not an issue (but i don't have the whole picture.. , so `<any string>,<any boolean>` could also cause it..by small chance)

Comment: please *add(/increase) logging* to `handleUserStatusChangedEvent`! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from Maziz, shouldn't the line setField be before the mvc call?

```
@ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(booleans = {true, false})
    void changeUserStatus_shouldEnableOrDisableTheUser(boolean enabled) throws Exception {
        // Some test setup here

        ChangeUserStatusRequest request = new ChangeUserStatusRequest()
                .setEnabled(enabled);

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userEventSQSListener, "keycloakService", keycloakService);

        String responseString = mockMvc.perform(patch(USERS_BASE_URL + "/{id}/status", id)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse()
                .getContentAsString();

        // Some assertions here

        assertThat(userEventSQSListener.getKeycloakService()).isEqualTo(keycloakService);

        await().atMost(10, SECONDS)
                .untilAsserted(() -> verify(keycloakService).changeUserStatus(anyString(), anyBoolean())); // Fails to verify method call
    }
```

and if this still does not work you can replace that line with

```
org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.setInternalState(UserEventSQSListener.class, "keycloakService", keycloakService);
```

but the general idea remains the same.

Comment: You are right. Although it didn't solve the issue, I understood that the real problem was not the injection process. So, I double-checked the AWS-related configurations and found the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Did you debug the KeyClockService in the UserEventSQSListener? Did you see if the object is type proxy something indicating a mock object?

Regardless of the answer, before you call mockMvc.perform, can use

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(UserEventSQSListener, "keycloakService", keycloakService /*the mock object*/)
```

Run again. Let me know if it's ok or not.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Using the exact line didn't work due to NullPointerException. But, I changed it a little and updated the question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @RezaEbrahimpour the setField should go before the mvc call in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can be related to using `@SqsListener`, so try putting this annotation to `UserIntegrationTest`:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```